# Android/Java: Enum methods crashing app

Tags: java, android

My enum declaration:

```
public enum Note { A, A_SHARP, B, C, C_SHARP, D, D_SHARP,
    E, F, F_SHARP, G, G_SHARP;

    public String toString(Note note) {
        if (note == Note.A)
            return "A";
        else if (note == Note.A_SHARP)
            return "A#";
        else if (note == Note.B)
            return "B";
        else if (note == Note.C)
            return "C";
        else if (note == Note.C_SHARP)
            return "C#";
        else if (note == Note.D)
            return "D";
        else if (note == Note.D_SHARP)
            return "D#";
        else if (note == Note.E)
            return "E";
        else if (note == Note.F)
            return "F";
        else if (note == Note.F_SHARP)
            return "F#";
        else if (note == Note.G)
            return "G";
        else if (note == Note.G_SHARP)
            return "G#";
        else
            return "";
    }

    public Note getNext() {
        int index = ordinal();
        index++;
        if (index > values().length)
            return values()[0];
        else
            return values()[index];
    }
}
```

Whenever I call either of these two methods, my app crashes. Here is where I call them:

```
public void ChangeSound(View v) {
    note = note.getNext();
    tvSounds.setText(note.toString(note));
}
```

ChangeSound() is an onClick method for a button. If I remove both lines in ChangeSound(), the code works as it should, but if either of the two lines are in there, the app crashes on the button click. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance!!

EDIT**
note is a variable of type Note

Thank you everyone! It was returning null (look at Jason C's answers (my comment)). All of this was helpful for me!

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? Is there a specific exception?

Comment: One of the downvoted answers below is not the answer but is a good suggestion; use a switch for the toString.

Comment: Since you say note.toString(note) causes the problem also, it is more likely that 'note' is null. Ensure this is not the case, and consider making Note.toString(Note) static so that it can handle nulls. See my answer below.

Comment: Please clear this up so that Tala and myself can sleep tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by "crashes", and you also do not show enough context (what is 'note'?) but the most likely cause *based on the fact that you stated either of those two lines crash* seems to be that 'note' is null. If 'note' is null then ChangeSound will throw a NullPointerException. You need to make sure that if ChangeSound is assuming 'note' is not null, that that is actually the case.

Also you should make toString(Note) a static method, and define a non-static toString() override. This will give Note.toString(Note) the ability to handle nulls correctly:

```
public static String toString (Note n) {
    return n == null ? "" : n.toString();
}
```

Edit: As noted in other answers, you should use >= instead of > (even == would be sufficient), that is also a potential problem.

Comment: You're right it was returning null. I put the initialization of the variable in the wrong place (rookie mistake). I'm very disappointed in myself haha.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `>=` since probably you're getting some OutOfBoundsException

```
if (index >= values().length)
        return values()[0];
    else
        return values()[index];
}
```

Also instead of switch you could sth like that:

```
public enum Note { A("A"), A_SHARP("A#"), B("B");

private String s;
public Note (String s) {
    this.s = s;
}
public String toString() {
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Actually, >= is not necessary. Since 'index' is a result of ordinal(), it will not exceed values().length - 1.

Comment: index++ is done after that, that will be the cause of the problem.

Comment: The original poster did say that if either of the two lines were present, the app crashes. Your answer is totally correct, but it wouldn't cause note.toString(note) to fail.

Comment: @JasonC, as far I understood the question poster said that problem is there when both lines are there and problem should be in one of them.

Comment: The poster wrote, "if either of the two lines are in there, the app crashes on the button click".

Comment: I guess author tried removing both lines and leaving both lines. Never tried to leave one of them and comment another. Hope that he will clear our doubts here... + second line has no problems.

Comment: Agreed, it is unclear. The second line has problems if note is null (notice that toString(Note) is not a static method).

Comment: getNext method cannot return null. It can only fail with outOfbounds

Comment: Ha. We need the poster to clear this up. What I meant was, the second line has problems with 'note' being null, *presuming* that the poster meant that commenting out the first line but leaving the second was tried and failed. Definitely *not* the case, as you say, if the first line is left as well (although note.getNext() would fail with a NPE, not OOB).

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
if (index > values().length)
```

to this:

```
if (index >= values().length)
```

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you, this would've also posed a problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue has already been spotted by the other answers. Note however that you could simplify your code in two ways:

- by associating the String representation of the notes with the enum constants directly
- by using a modulus instead of your if/else in `getNext`

It could look like:

```
public enum Note { A("A"), A_SHARP("A#"), B("B"), C("C"), C_SHARP("C#"), D("D"),
      D_SHARP("D#"), E("E"), F("F"), F_SHARP("F#"), G("G"), G_SHARP("G#");

    private final String noteName;
    Note(String noteName) {
        this.noteName = noteName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return noteName;
    }

    public Note getNext() {
        int nextIndex = (ordinal() + 1) % values().length;
        return values()[nextIndex];
    }
}
```

And in your main code:

```
note = note.getNext();
tvSounds.setText(note.toString());
```

Comment: A static toString(Note) would round this off nicely, keeping with the OP's presumably intended interface. The modulus is elegant but not necessary in this situation, ordinal()+1 will be values.length() at most.

Comment: @JasonC (a) `toString(Note)` seems unnecessary (you need a note instance in both cases, so it makes more sense to call `note.toString()`, than `Note.toString(note)` (b) `G_SHARP.ordinal() + 1` is equal to `values.length()`, so `values()[G_SHARP.ordinal() + 1]` would throw an exception.

Comment: (a) Agreed completely re: unnecessary -- *except* that the OP had one, so I presume he wants it. The static version could handle nulls. (b) I was proposing "if (nextIndex == values.length()) nextIndex = 0" instead of modulus. I was not proposing leaving out the check entirely. :-)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I'm newish to java (I'm comin' from C). I didn't know you could do this.